# SQLException deadlocked: does the exception contains the query text executed somewhere?

Tags: c#, t-sql, ado.net

The SQLException "was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim" is quite common ;-)

Does the exception contains the query text executed somewhere ?
Is it possible to obtain ?

Thks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not in your exception. You SHOULD KNOW WHAT YOU DID - and the exception just tells you that YOU Deadlocked. You should know what SQL youwere executing at this moment.

For the rest, use the query profiler and other information you obtain from teh server (check http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832524 for some tips, or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937573(v=SQL.80).aspx to find out what OTHER scripts you deadlock with. THis is, though, for very obbvious security reasons, something onl adins do.

Comment: It's so easy to say that. Well first debugging exists because you don't know what is happening. Which means you don't know what it did. A database has tons of stored procedures. Locating the involved ones should be as easy as 1 2 3.  And no I won't use any sql tracing on sql server.

Comment: You wrote "for very obvious security reasons". Debugging has never been an "addin" anywhere. Exceptions have never been secured anywhere. If i follow what you write, on exception the stack trace should not be dumped. Because you should know what your program does when it crashed. Because there are 'security reason' noone knows about. Sure if your habit is to let exceptions display to everyone, mine is not.